# How do I open a windows explorer window with a specific folder selected

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a winform application and this winform application has created few files. I want to implement "find target" function in my application to show those files. Those files located in a same folder. See the picture:

[image: find target functionality as in windows xp]

Let's say that I have created few files in `"C:\Test\"` folder and this folder has this file: `"C:\Test\File1.txt"`. How to create "find target" functionality using VB.NET?

Comment: The question is really "How do I open a windows explorer window with a specific folder selected" and has nothing to do with shortcuts and "find target". (I found by comments on my answer that I now have deleted)

Comment: @Stefan: Sorry about that, but thanks for your attempt to help me.

Comment: No problem. ;-) But please update your question so other knows why the answers are the way they are now. As it is now, bypassers will be confused by the answers that answer a totally different question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`Process.Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to start the Windows Explorer:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select," & "FILETOSELECT")
```

With the `/select, [file]` parameter, you can highlight the file.

Comment: If `FILETOSELECT` might include spaces, you should make sure it's quoted: `Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select,""" & "FILETOSELECT" & """")`

Comment: For C# `Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select, \"" + path_to_file + "\"");`

Comment: it works. But the bad about this is that it will open new `explorer.exe` processes (see TaskManager)

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152457) where it specifies the arguments, explorer.exe takes in

Then use [`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx)