# Button that opens Application Path + specific folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm kind of confused on how to do this. What I want to do is when I click `Button1`, my program will open a folder in Explorer, and the second button will open a file as a text file.

Here's my code:

Button 1

```
   Process.Start("explorer.exe", Application.ExecutablePath + "\mvram.biz")
```

Button 2

```
   Process.Start("Notepad.Exe", "README.txt")
```

My problem is everytime I click the button it will open My Documents. It must open the APPpath+Specific Folder.

EDIT:

```
Public Class Form1



Private Sub ExcisionButtonDefault5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles ExcisionButtonDefault5.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ExcisionButtonDefault1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExcisionButtonDefault1.Click
    Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) & "\mvram.biz\"
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", path)
End Sub

Private Sub ExcisionButtonDefault2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExcisionButtonDefault2.Click
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", Application.StartupPath & "\Documents")
End Sub

Private Sub ExcisionButtonDefault3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExcisionButtonDefault3.Click
    Process.Start("Notepad.Exe", "/select," & "README.txt")
End Sub

Private Sub ExcisionButtonDefault4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExcisionButtonDefault4.Click
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\Presentation")
End Sub

Private Sub ExcisionButtonDefault6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExcisionButtonDefault6.Click
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.mvram.biz")
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: When you say "everytime I click the button" do you mean `Button1`?

Comment: Yes sir Button 1

The button 2 is I'm trying to open Readme.txt but the file wasn't found

Kindly help me sir currently stuck with this one

Comment: Look at this : [Example of your requirement][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532222/how-do-i-open-a-windows-explorer-window-with-a-specific-folder-selected

Comment: I already tried that sir @Brainarts .
The problem sir can I make the path == to Application path + Specific folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it opens a random location is because you are intending to execute a wrong path (whole app path + other app). You have to choose the directory. Try this code:

```
Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) & "\mvram.biz"
Process.Start("explorer.exe", path)
```

Other option:

```
Dim path As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\mvram.biz"
```

I personally prefer to use absolute paths rather than relative ones (just the name of the file when referring to the same directory).

Comment: Sir I tried it but it just open My Documents. It always like this I don't get it.

Comment: @blademaster Then your exe is in my documents. Set a break point in path and see the value it takes. This code should work perfectly.

Comment: @blademaster because this is what you want, don't you? Opening a file called "mvram.biz" which is located in the same folder than your executable.

Comment: Sir the path of my project is in

C:\Users\tales\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\bin\debug

Comment: @blademaster I was about to suggest you to write \ at the end ("\mvram.biz\") to let VB.NET that it is a folder. But I tested it withouth doing that and it works anyway. You should be able to get what you want with the code I have posted. Please, confirm that you have written it properly (or show us your version, by updating the question with your updated code).

Comment: @blademaster I suggest you to use the second option (Environment.CurrentDirectory), I have tested it thoroughly and know that it works for sure in any situation (unless there is a problem in your Windows/File system/.NET).

Comment: @blademaster and ExcisionButtonDefault1_Click is not working I presume. It should work fine. Your original code was wrong, I have proposed the correction, which should work. If you keep saying that it does not work I cannot do anything (other than, eventually, deleting this answer because of not seeing the point of keeping it here). I have recommended you to use Environment.CurrentDirectory, but Application.ExecutablePath should work too (now when you get the directory name). If nothing of this works, worry about your computer but I cannot do anything else.

Comment: I removed the excisions sir I think my computer is the problem anyway sir Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

To open a specific folder in FileExplorer, you can try passing this argument:

```
Dim x as string = "FolderPath"
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/root,x")
```

Or you could pass the argument `"/select,x"`, which will open File Explorer with the folder selected, but not opened. This [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853) may be helpful. Or you can just have the file address, like you tried above, and it will open to the correct location.

And then to open a txt file, all you need to do is:

```
Process.Start("FileAddress")
```

This will open the file in its default editor.

HTH

Comment: It just open in my documents sir. I don't get it the directory must

C:\Users\tales\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\bin\debug

Comment: @blademaster If you put `" C:\Users\tales\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\bin\debug\"` with the \ at the end, it still opens your documents folder?